# Images not displayed in my profile page

Tags: support, profile-page, markdown, images

I'm trying to display these images and text in my profile page:

```
Thanks for supporting Firefox and the Mozilla mission to build a better Web for all!
<a href="https://affiliates.mozilla.org/referral/68975/">
    <img src="https://affiliates.mozilla.org/media/uploads/image_banners/c02fc7194d4fff8d1d221b098d67900118900685.png" alt="">
</a>

Anti-IF Campaign:
<a href="http://www.antiifcampaign.com">
  <img height="60" width="120"
  src="http://antiifcampaign.com/assets/banner_ive-joined.gif"
  alt="I have joined Anti-IF Campaign"></a>
```

I can't understand why they are not displayed, no errors in network console; if important I'm testing this in Chrome under a proxy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first image shows up just fine for me in your profile (here and on Stack Overflow).

The second doesn't. Testing on my "about me" page, removing the width and height attributes fixes it.

This also seems to work:

```
<a href="http://www.antiifcampaign.com">
  <img src="http://antiifcampaign.com/assets/banner_ive-joined.gif" width="120" height="60" alt="I have joined Anti-IF Campaign">
</a>
```

i.e.:

- change the order of the attributes to match what is specified here: [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)
- avoid line breaks in the `<img>` tag (no idea why that helps)

Comment: True, there are very strict rules about how img tag can be used inside markup, swaying even a bit means it simply won't work.